# How do i set array of string as a field in mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a meeting model in mongoose with the following fields-

```
    const meetingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    meeting_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    time: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    organiser: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    attendies: []
}, { timestamps: true} );
```

but when i tried to create a meeting through postman it gave me the error of "Cannot POST /api/meeting/post".
Is there anything wrong with my attendies field as i want to set it as an array of string and also is there a better way to set date and time field than just String?
i am new to nodejs and mongoose

Comment: The schema looks functional. What error is being produced in the app/postman for the request?

Comment: It returns some html with a pre tag saying Cannot POST /api/meeting/post

Answer (score 0):

When you set no type for an [array](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays), the type will be [`Mixed`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) so anything goes. To specifically set it as an array of `String` use the following:

```
const meetingSchema = new Schema({
  attendees: [String],
  datetime: Date,
});
```

Date + Time are both stored in a single UTC `Date` object

Comment: i want to give date and time as input. i dont want it to get auto-generated